# Data reload after query editor in Power BI

Tags: performance, powerbi, powerquery

I have some huge csv files and it takes me quite a long time to load them in Power BI. I assume that it's normal when it's the first time that I load them. But, here is the problem. Every time I alter the data in Query Editor and then close & apply my changes, Power BI will reload the whole files and take once again a long time. Isn't it possible that Power BI only "reload" or "reread" the altered data ? (I know the "Enable load" & "Include in report refresh" features but it doesn't help)

I don't know if I made myself clear, if not, let me know what you don't understand.

The main problem is here related to the performance of Power BI which always reload the whole file(s) when you alter it.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no Power BI solution for this - ref the many popular Ideas on their Community site for "incremental load" etc.

My typical workarounds are:

1. Pre-load CSV data to SQL Server or similar. PBI development will be much quicker (e.g. effective test filters) and you can possibly pre-aggregate in SQL.
2. Pre-process Queries using Excel Power Query, saving the results as Excel Tables.  You can copy and paste the Query definitions between PBI and Excel.

Comment: SQL Server seems to be the best solution for me too. Thanks for the answer.